# Regex to not match consecutive numbers in a string c#

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

My requirement is to enforce a password policy which contains a rule to not have consecutive numbers i.e. "pass1234","abc12","12tab" etc. should be not allowed. my current regex is:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(password,
                    @"^(?!(?:0(?=1)|1(?=2)|2(?=3)|3(?=4)|4(?=5)|5(?=6)|6(?=7)|7(?=8)|8(?=9)|9(?=0))\d{1,}|(?:0(?=9)|1(?=0)|2(?=1)|3(?=2)|4(?=3)|5(?=4)|6(?=5)|7(?=6)|8(?=7)|9(?=8))\d{1,})[a-zA-Z\d]+$")))
```

But the above regex matches strings that start with numbers i.e. "12abc", "12pass"  but not the strings that contain numbers in between the string like "ab12pass","pass1234" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it without using regular expressions if you really meant you don't want consecutive increasing or decreasing numbers.

```
private static bool NoConsecutiveIncreasingOrDecreasingNumbers(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        return true;

    char prev = str[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        char current = str[i];
        if ('0' < current && current < '9' && 
            '0' < prev && prev < '9' && 
            (prev + 1 == current || current + 1 == prev ))
            return false;
        prev = current;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Just remove that last condition in the `if` if you really did mean any consecutive numbers.

Comment: all the other rules are defined using regex.

Comment: @Siddharth You can always do one check with regular expressions and another with regular code.  Trying to create one monster regular expression is IMHO very hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Regex to detect if there are ascending or descending numbers.

```
^((?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?|(?:9(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=0|$))?0?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eA7_vpAKCqb-Iq8Q)

Comment: How will the above regex handle passwords i.e. if the string contains characters other than numbers for eg. pass1234

Comment: @Siddharth If you remove the ^ at the beginning you can have characters in front of the numbers and if you remove the $ at the end you can have characters behind the numbers.

Comment: @Siddharth If this answer helped you, please mark your question as answered :)

Comment: when i try to fetch the result using the following statement 
var match = Regex.Match(password, @"((?:0(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=9|$))?9?|(?:9(?=8|$))?(?:8(?=7|$))?(?:7(?=6|$))?(?:6(?=5|$))?(?:5(?=4|$))?(?:4(?=3|$))?(?:3(?=2|$))?(?:2(?=1|$))?(?:1(?=0|$))?0?)");  doesn't give the right result.